# How do you indent when creating a multi line file from terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So I need a command to make the output look like this:

```
    [core]
            repositoryformatversion = 0
            filemode = true
            bare = false
            logallrefupdates = true
    [remote "origin"]
            url = ssh://git@github.com/user/address.git
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [branch "master"]
            remote = origin
            merge = refs/heads/master
```

I have tried the following,

```
printf "[core]\n    repositoryformatversion = 0\n   filemode = true\n   bare = false\n  logallrefupdates = true\n   logallrefupdates = true\n[remote "origin"]\n    url = ssh://git@github.com/user/address.git\n   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*\n[branch "master"]\n    remote = origin\n   merge = refs/heads/master" > config
```

But it creates a file with these contents

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
logallrefupdates = true
[remote origin]
url = ssh://git@github.com/user/address.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch master]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

How can I make it wehre it outputs this in the format first stated?

Comment: What you've written should work. Perhaps you are using a non-standard shell with a builtin printf.  Or maybe you have an alias or function for printf defined.

Comment: Create your file without indent and then: `sed -E 's/^[^[]/\t&/' file`

Comment: saavedra29's answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `printf` for this at all. Just use a here document with `cat`:

```
cat <<'EOF' > config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@github.com/user/address.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
EOF
```

Or, define a variable with the contents

```
config='
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@github.com/user/address.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
'

printf '%s\n' "$config" > config
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is better? I am new to terminal

Comment: Primarily, it's more readable. The input *looks* like the output, rather than embedding `\n` escape sequences to represent newlines.

Answer (score 0):

After "\n" you could use "\t" to create tabs.